# Looking for elegant way of searching through an array of strings for duplicate entries. Brute force method works

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a file of alphanumeric VIN numbers from vehicles (saved as strings).    I need to parse through this file and determine

1) Is a VIN duplicated?  If so, how many times

2) Write the duplicated VIN and the total number of duplicates to a text file

I have gotten it to work using the brute force method dual nested For loops.  Am looking for a more elegant way to parse the strings.  I'm using Java 7 in NetBeans 8.2 and it doesn't appear to like using the .set or hashmap.

Constraints

1) The VINs may be in any order

2) The duplicates can be scattered through the file at random

/* a) Open input and output files
            */

```
        try {

        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));//csv file
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("DuplicateVINs.txt"));
```

/* b) Read in file line by line
            then slice out the 17 digit VIN from the extra data I don't care about
            */

```
        while ((thisLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
            l = thisLine.substring(1, 18);
            linesVIN.add(l.split(","));//why does this split have to be here?
        }
```

/*c) Now that the List is full calculate its size and then write to array of strings
            */

```
            String[][] inputArray = new String[linesVIN.size()][];
                             i=linesVIN.size();
                             System.out.println(i);
             linesVIN.toArray(inputArray);
```

/* d) Will use two nested For loos to look for duplicates
                    */

```
            countj=0;
            countk=0;

        for (int j = 1;j<=i-1; j++){ //j loop                  
            duplicateVIN=Arrays.toString(inputArray[j]);
                for(int k=1;k<=i-1;k++){
                  if(duplicateVIN.equals(Arrays.toString(inputArray[k]))){
                      countk=countk+1;
                      foundFlag=true;
                } else{
                      //
                      if(countk>=2){
                          //if(j!=k){
                           System.out.println(duplicateVIN + countk);    
                          //} // see if removes the first duplicate
                      }
                        foundFlag=false;
                        countk=0;
                    } 
                  } //ends k loop
                countj=j;

        } //ends j loop


       } //Completes the try
```

[2q3CDZC90JH1qqqqq], 3

[2q4RC1NG1JR1qqqqq], 4

[2q3CDZC96KH1qqqqq], 2

[1q4PJMDN8KD1qqqqq], 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using Java 7 in NetBeans 8.2 and it doesn't appear to like using the .set or hashmap.

Your first step should be to figure out what you're doing wrong with a map. A hashmap is the perfect solution for this problem, and is really what you should be using.

Here's a broad example of how the solution would work, using the information you provided.

```
Map<String,Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
while ((thisLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
        l = thisLine.substring(1, 18);

        if(countMap.containsKey(l)){
              countMap.put(l, countMap.get(l)+1);
        }else{
          countMap.put(l,1);
       }
    }
```

I'm assuming that the while loop your provided is properly iterating over all VIN numbers.

After this while loop is completed you would just need to output the values of each key, similar to this:

```
 for(String vin : countMap.keySet()){
        System.out.println("VIN: "+vin+" COUNT: "+countMap.get(vin));
    }
```

If I've read your problem correctly, there is no need for a nested loop.